# Mixed multilevel list in CSS

Tags: html, css

everyone!
How can I make mixed multilevel list in CSS similar like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCpx.png) result

I try this variant. But this paste counter to unordered list

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] of your issue when asking here, not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: `ol li` selects every `li` that is a descendant of the `ol`, no matter how many levels down, and no matter whether their parent might actually be a `ul`. If you want to select only `li` that are a child of `ol`, then use the child combinator: `ol > li`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a multi-level list like the one you've described using HTML and CSS, you can use nested ul (unordered list) and li (list item) elements. The structure of the list will represent the hierarchy of the chapters and titles. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Multi-Level List Example</title>
    <style>
        ul,
        li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .chapter-list {
            counter-reset: chapter;
        }

        .chapter-list>li:before {
            counter-increment: chapter;
            content: counter(chapter) ". ";
        }

        .title-list {
            counter-reset: title;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .title-list>li:before {
            counter-increment: title;
            content: counter(chapter) "." counter(title) " ";
        }

        .sub-title-list {
            counter-reset: sub-title;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }

        .sub-title-list>li:before {
            counter-increment: sub-title;
            content: counter(chapter) "." counter(title) "." counter(sub-title) " ";
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="chapter-list">
        <li>Chapter 1</li>
        <li>Chapter 2
            <ul class="title-list">
                <li>Title 1</li>
                <li>Title 2
                    <ul class="sub-title-list">
                        <li>Sub 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Chapter 3</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use counting

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") ". Link " counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>    
        <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```